# Working with PMD rules

Tags: testing, rules, pmd

How to work with PMD rules. Where to place that xml file and run against my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse look at oneofthelions answer.

Here an Ant task to generate a PMD report (you will need to substitute the properties according to your project structure):

```
<target name="create-pmd-report" description="Generates a PMD report">

    <fail unless="target.reports.pmd" message="target.reports.pmd not set"/>

    <delete dir="${target.reports.pmd}"/>
    <mkdir  dir="${target.reports.pmd}"/>

    <pmd rulesetfiles="src/main/resources/pmd/ruleset.xml">

        <formatter type="xml" toFile="${target.reports.pmd}/pmd-report.xml" linkPrefix="${src.main}/"/>

        <fileset dir="${src.main}">
            <include name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>

    </pmd>

    <xslt
        in="${target.reports.pmd}/pmd-report.xml"
        style="${pmd.home}/etc/xslt/pmd-report.xslt"
        out="${target.reports.pmd}/pmd-report.html"
    />

</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, If you are using maven.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
<configuration>
    <targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>
    <linkXref>false</linkXref>
    <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
    <failurePriority>1</failurePriority>
    <rulesets>
        <ruleset>${pom.basedir}/pmd-rulesets.xml</ruleset>
    </rulesets>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

I wrote a [tutorial](http://www.techtraits.com/writting-pretty-code-with-pmd/)  about it a while back with some [sample code](http://www.techtraits.ca/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/helloworld.zip).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows->Preferences in Eclipse, to check if PMD is already installed.

If not then click on Help->Install New Software->place this link `http://pmd.sourceforge.net/eclipse`and add it. It will install the PMD rules for you.

If you have your own PMD rules to run against your code. Then right click your project->PMD->clear all the rules and add the PMD xml you have and click OK.

Then right click your project->PMD->Check code with PMD. It will tell you the errors.
Once you clear the voilations, there is also a option to generate report. Which says that your code is clean and no voilations